# How to check if two Torch tensors or matrices are equal?

Tags: lua, torch

I need a Torch command that checks if two tensors have the same content, and returns TRUE if they have the same content.

For example:

```
local tens_a = torch.Tensor({9,8,7,6});
local tens_b = torch.Tensor({9,8,7,6});

if (tens_a EQUIVALENCE_COMMAND tens_b) then ... end
```

What should I use in this script instead of `EQUIVALENCE_COMMAND` ?

I tried simply with `==` but it does not work.

Comment: To allow for floating point differences, see [Check if PyTorch tensors are equal within epsilon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53374928/5353461).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

```
torch.eq(a, b)
```

[`eq()`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#torcheqa-b) implements the `==` operator comparing each element in `a` with `b` (if b is a value) or each element in `a` with its corresponding element in `b` (if `b` is a tensor).

---

**Alternative from @deltheil:**

```
torch.all(tens_a.eq(tens_b))
```

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, with present torch, `.eq` returns a tensor whereas `.equal` actually returns a bool.

Comment: Is there an approximate version of this? I would like something to compute the norm `||A - B||` and check if that's small (which is not the same as `A.allclose(B)`).

Answer (score 101):

This below solution worked for me:

```
torch.equal(tensorA, tensorB)
```

From [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.equal):

> `True` if two tensors have the same size and elements, `False` otherwise.

Comment: This answer should be the only one used for this issue as this function match the exact behaviour wanted by the OP + it is the most effective, if the tensors are not of same shape no computation is made.

Answer (score 33):

To compare tensors you can do element wise:

[`torch.eq`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=eq#torch.eq) is element wise:

```py
torch.eq(torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), torch.tensor([[1., 1.], [4., 4.]]))
tensor([[True, False], [False, True]])
```

Or [`torch.equal`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=eq#torch.equal) for the whole tensor exactly:

```py
torch.equal(torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3, 4.]]), torch.tensor([[1., 1.], [4., 4.]]))
# False
torch.equal(torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]))
    # True
```

But then you may be lost because at some point there are small differences you would like to ignore. For instance floats `1.0` and `1.0000000001` are pretty close and you may consider these are equal. For that kind of comparison you have [`torch.allclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=allclose#torch.allclose).

```py
torch.allclose(torch.tensor([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]]), torch.tensor([[1., 2.000000001], [3., 4.]]))
# True
```

At some point may be important to check element wise how many elements are equal, comparing to the full number of elements. If you have two tensors `dt1` and `dt2` you get number of elements of `dt1` as `dt1.nelement()`

And with this formula you get the percentage:

```py
print(torch.sum(torch.eq(dt1, dt2)).item()/dt1.nelement())
```

Comment: torch.allclose() is the one I was looking for.

Comment: How to do not equal to?

Answer (score 11):

Try this if you want to ignore small precision differences which are common for floats

```
torch.all(torch.lt(torch.abs(torch.add(tens_a, -tens_b)), 1e-12))
```

Comment: alternatively you may use [`torch.allclose()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=allclose#torch.allclose).

Answer (score 1):

This solution also works fine for me and seems more natural.

```
torch.all(tensorA == tensorB)
```

gives output as:

if equivalent gives output as `tensor(1, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)`
else : `tensor(0, device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.uint8)`

Answer (score -2):

You can **convert** the two tensors to numpy arrays:

```
local tens_a = torch.Tensor((9,8,7,6));
local tens_b = torch.Tensor((9,8,7,6));

a=tens_a.numpy()
b=tens_b.numpy()
```

and then something like

```
np.sum(a==b)
4
```

would give you a fairly good idea of how equals are they.

Comment: This is inefficient and unnecessary. Just use pytorch functions.