# Check if PyTorch tensors are equal within epsilon

Tags: pytorch

How do I check if two PyTorch tensors are semantically equal?

Given floating point errors, I want to know if the the elements differ only by a small epsilon value.

Answer (score 16):

At the time of writing, this is a undocumented function in the latest stable release (0.4.1), but the documentation is in the `master (unstable)` branch.

[`torch.allclose()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html?highlight=allclose#torch.allclose) will return a boolean indicating whether all element-wise differences are equal allowing for a margin of error.

Additionally, there's the undocumented `isclose()`:

```
>>> torch.isclose(torch.Tensor([1]), torch.Tensor([1.00000001]))
tensor([1], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Comment: It is on stable now

Comment: It would be nice to have some function to test tensor closeness based on tensor norm.