# tensor equality and boolean as return value

Tags: pytorch, tensor

So, I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996281/how-to-check-if-two-torch-tensors-or-matrices-are-equal) on SO

I'm trying to equate two tensors

`torch.equal(x_valid[0], x_valid[:1])` returns `False` whereas 
`torch.all(torch.eq(x_valid[0], x_valid[:1]))` returns `tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)`

I know for a fact that both tensors are same like first value of `x_valid` so why torch.equal returns `False`?

except the fact that `x_valid[0]` returns `([0, 0, ...,0])` & `x_valid[:1]` returns `([[0, 0, ...,0]])`

but type of both of them is still `tensor`. So I can't really understand why the output of first query is `False`

Answer (score 1):

`torch.equal(tensor1, tensor2)` return `True` if two tensors have the same size and elements, `False` otherwise. Check [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.equal).

Example:

```
y = torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0]])
print(y[0], y[0].shape)
print(y[:1], y[:1].shape)
print(torch.equal(y[0], y[:1]))
print(torch.equal(y[0], y[:1][0])) # (torch.Size([3]), torch.Size([3]))
```

output:

```
tensor([0, 0, 0]) torch.Size([3])
tensor([[0, 0, 0]]) torch.Size([1, 3])
False
True
```

Whereas, `torch.eq(input, other, out=None)` computes element-wise equality. Here, one important to note is that the second argument can be a number or a tensor whose shape is [broadcastable](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html#broadcasting-semantics) with the first argument.

Comment: But how is my tensor1, tensor2 different in size and elements. Is it because of tuple containing list of tensors and other actual tuple containing tensor?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan, `y[:1]` has an extra dimension in it. See yourself using `y[:1].size()`