# Comparison of 2 tensors returns RuntimeError

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

In my tests I need to `assertEqual` 2 tensor values. Sometimes both of them are tensors of <s>zero</s> actually **any values**, for example:

```py
def test_preprocess_text_single_line(self):
  self.assertEqual(torch.tensor([0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]), torch.tensor([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0]))
```

Which leads to `RuntimeError`:

```bash
self.assertEqual(torch.tensor([0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]), torch.tensor([0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 8, 0]))

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

How to avoid that?

Comment: Maybe the answer to your question is on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996281/how-to-check-if-two-torch-tensors-or-matrices-are-equal ? I tested it on my end with two zero tensors and it returns True

Comment: @bmasri thank you, but I actually have a dictionary with tensors as values with quite complex structure. There's somewhere a comparison internally, which fails on comparison of tensors full of zeros.