# comparing two tensors in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor, random-seed, equivalence

I've already tried the solutions described in this question: [How to check if two Torch tensors or matrices are equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32996281/how-to-check-if-two-torch-tensors-or-matrices-are-equal)

and I'm not having any luck for some reason.

I'm just trying to test reproducibility of my random number seed as an example:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import torch

def seed_everything(seed):
  random.seed(seed)
  os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)
  torch.manual_seed(seed)
  torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
  torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed) # for cases of multiple gpus
  torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

seed_everything(4321)
a = torch.rand(1, 3)
print(f"Tensor a: {a}")

a_expect = torch.tensor([[0.1255, 0.5377, 0.6564]])
print(f"Tensor a_expect: {a_expect}")

equal = torch.equal(a, a_expect)
print(f"torch.equal: {equal}")

eq = torch.eq(a, a_expect)
print(f"torch.eq: {eq}")

close = torch.allclose(a, a_expect)
print(f"torch.allclose: {close}")

diff = torch.all(torch.lt(torch.abs(torch.add(a, -a_expect)), 1e-12))
print(f"torch.all(lt(abs(add,1e-12))): {diff}")
```

output

```
Tensor a: tensor([[0.1255, 0.5377, 0.6564]])
Tensor a_expect: tensor([[0.1255, 0.5377, 0.6564]])
torch.equal: False
torch.eq: tensor([[False, False, False]])
torch.allclose: False
torch.all(lt(abs(add,1e-12))): False
```

(I'm using pytorch 1.12.1 and my machine is an apple M1 mac)

(I also tried downgrading to 1.10.2 and it made no difference)

Thank you for any clues

**Update**: I see the trouble now is the representation of the tensor when printed is truncated.  If I turn the random number tensor into a list, the true source of the difference is revealed.

```
 values = a.tolist()
 print(f"Tensor values: {values}")
```

output is:

```
Tensor values: [0.1255376935005188, 0.5376683473587036, 0.6563868522644043]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `atol` parameter in allclose method

The allclose method check using this formula

[image]

Therefore, since the number of significant figures is up to four decimal places, the value of `atol` should be 1e-4.

Below is the example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import torch

def seed_everything(seed):
  random.seed(seed)
  os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
  np.random.seed(seed)
  torch.manual_seed(seed)
  torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
  torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed) # for cases of multiple gpus
  torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

seed_everything(4321)
a = torch.rand(1, 3)

a_expect = torch.tensor([[0.1255, 0.5377, 0.6564]])

close = torch.allclose(a, a_expect, atol=1e-4)
print(f"torch.allclose: {close}")
```

result:

```
torch.allclose: True
```